# How to scrape phone no using python when it show after clicked

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape phone no but phone no only displays after clicked so please is it possible to scrape phone no directly using python?My code scrape phone no but with starr***. here is the link from where I want to scrape phone no:https://hipages.com.au/connect/abcelectricservicespl/service/126298 please guide me!
 here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):

    try:
        title = (soup.find('h1', class_="sc-AykKI",id=False).text)
    except:
        title = 'Empty Title'
    print(title)

    try:
        contact_person = (soup.findAll('span', class_="Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee",id=False)[0].text)
    except:
        contact_person = 'Empty Person'
    print(contact_person)

    try:
        location = (soup.findAll('span', class_="Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee",id=False)[1].text)
    except:
        location = 'Empty location'
    print(location)

    try:
        cell = (soup.findAll('span', class_="Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee",id=False)[2].text)
    except:
        cell = 'Empty Cell No'
    print(cell)

    try:
        phone = (soup.findAll('span', class_="Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee",id=False)[3].text)
    except:
        phone = 'Empty Phone No'
    print(phone)

    try:
        Verify_ABN = (soup.find('p', class_="sc-AykKI").text)
    except:
        Verify_ABN = 'Empty Verify_ABN'
    print(Verify_ABN)

    try:
        ABN = (soup.find('div', class_="box__Box-sc-1u3aqjl-0").find('a'))
    except:
        ABN = 'Empty ABN'
    print(ABN)



def main():
    #get data of detail page
    url = "https://hipages.com.au/connect/abcelectricservicespl/service/126298"
    #get_page(url)
    get_detail_data(get_page(url))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def Main():
    r = requests.get(
        "https://hipages.com.au/connect/abcelectricservicespl/service/126298")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    name = soup.find("h1", {'class': 'sc-AykKI'}).text
    print(name)
    person = soup.find(
        "span", {'class': 'Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee'}).text.strip()
    print(person)
    addr = soup.findAll(
        "span", {'class': 'Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee'})[1].text
    print(addr)
    print(re.search('phone\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', r.text).group(1))
    print(re.search('mobile\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', r.text).group(1))
    print(re.search('abn\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', r.text).group(1))
    print(re.search('website\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', r.text).group(1))


Main()
```

Output:

```
ABC Electric Services p/l
Mal
222 Henry Lawson DRV, Georges Hall NSW 2198
1800 801 828
0408 600 950
37137808989
www.abcelectricservices.com.au
```

Or if you would like to parse the full script:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyjsparser
import json
import re


def Main():
    r = requests.get(
        "https://hipages.com.au/connect/abcelectricservicespl/service/126298")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    phone = soup.findAll("script")[5]
    tree = pyjsparser.parse(phone.text)
    print(json.loads(tree["body"][0]["expression"]["right"]["value"]))


Main()
```

Another version:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json


def Main():
    r = requests.get(
        "https://hipages.com.au/connect/abcelectricservicespl/service/126298")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.findAll("script")[5].text
    source = re.search(r'__INITIAL_STATE__\s*=\s*"({.*})', data).group(1)
    kuku = json.loads(re.sub('(?<!\\\)\\\\"', '"', source))
    print(json.dumps(kuku, indent=4))


Main()
```

Comment: You can simplify regular expressions by using the 'raw' string specifier 'r', e.g. `r"string"` btw. it'll reduce the problem of having to count your backslashes.

Comment: @Todd will be nice to see how you will do it? as i still couldn't catch the point.

Comment: hi bro! I need some more help please. I follow your code for other things which I want to scrape like website link and ABN no but it shows an error please review code and fix it:
    # ABN and WEBSITE
    abn = soup.findall(
        "div", {'class': 'box__Box-sc-1u3aqjl-0 kxddET'}).find('a')
    print(abn)
    website = soup.findall(
        "div", {'class': 'sc-AykKC col__Col-sc-15n4ng3-0 hJfjKg'}).find('a')
    print(website)

Comment: @MuhammadAkram I've tested the code on my end and it's running good. are you running it on other url ?

Comment: Could you please add 2 line of code for website link and ABN No with your previous code?

Comment: @MuhammadAkram check updated answer. also i highly advise you if you are looking to scrape a multiple urls from the same website, so you can retrieve the full information from `script` better than parse the html source which will save a huge time.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ_αмєяιcαηThank you bro! I'm new to web scraping. Could you please suggest me some youtube videos or anything else from where I can learn web scraping at advance level.

Comment: @MuhammadAkram [bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Phone number exists in page source already.
There is a script in page source starting with `window.__INITIAL_STATE__`, it contains an object having data against multiple providers so you can get phone number for all of them from here or simply load this object in json and on basis of store as a key, get phone number against that store

Comment: `soup.findAll("script")[5].text` and then `re.findall(r'__INITIAL_STATE__\s*=\s*"({.*})', variable)`