# Find nested JS object value from specific script tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: javascript, python, django, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a site with beautiful soup to grab image/s, this has worked fine for every site so far and I have even managed to create some custom case-types.  But one particular site is causing me issues as iit returns all the images in a JavaScript object wrapped inline in a script tag.  The object is quite large as it holds all the product info, the specific bit I am looking for is nested pretty deep in productArticleDetails > [the product id] > normalImages > thumbnail > [the image path]. Like so:

```
<script>
var productArticleDetails = {
   ...
   '0399310001': {
      ...
      'normalImages': [
         {
            'thumbnail': '//image-path.jpg',
            ...
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So I am looking to just extract the image path.

It is also not the only thing wrapped in a script tag in the returned 'soup', there are loads of other javascript tags in the code.  So far I have saved the HTML to a variable and then run:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
```

So I am left with an object that contains all the `<script>` elements from `html`

Somehow within that `scripts` object I need to find that specific node in the correct chunk of JS and return the value of the `thumbnail` node that is nested under the `normalImages` node, which in turn would be nested underneath a string of numbers which is ultimately all saved to the `productArticleDetails` var.

I figure I need to do a `for` loop over the `scripts` object but have had no luck figuring out how to extract that specific bit of data.  Everything else I have seen works on the assumption there is only 1 bit of javaScript and the value you're looking for is not nested.

Can anyone help? Cheers.

Comment: if you posted a valid `script`, i will let you access it easily.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<script type="application/ld+json">
var productArticleDetails = {
                    "@context" : "https://schema.org",
                    "@type" : "BreadcrumbList",
                    "itemListElement": [ {"@type":"ListItem","thumbnail":"//image-path.jpg","item":{"@id":"https://www.myntra.com/","name":"Home"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"@id":"https://www.myntra.com/clothing","name":"Clothing"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"item":{"@id":"https://www.myntra.com/men-clothing","name":"Men Clothing"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"item":{"@id":"https://www.myntra.com/shirts","name":"Shirts"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":5,"item":{"@id":"https://www.myntra.com/formal-shirts-for-men","name":"Formal Shirts For Men"}} ]
                }
            </script>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

sc = soup.find("script").text

data = sc.split("=", 1)[1]


ld = json.loads(data)

# print(json.dumps(ld, indent=4))

print(ld["itemListElement"][0]["thumbnail"])
```

Output:

```
//image-path.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a simplifying assumption, say, that the object you want to parse has its final `}` flush with the beginning of the line, it's pretty easy:

```
import ast
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<script>
// we don't care about this script tag
</script>

<script>
var productArticleDetails = {
   '0399310001': {
      'normalImages': [
         {
            'thumbnail': '//image-path.jpg',
         }
      ]
   }
}

var someOtherThing = 42;
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for script in soup.find_all("script"):
    pattern = r"^var productArticleDetails = (.+?^})"

    if m := re.search(pattern, script.text, re.M | re.S):
        data = ast.literal_eval(m.group(1))
        break

print(data["0399310001"]["normalImages"][0]["thumbnail"])
```

Output:

```
//image-path.jpg
```

However, if you can't make this assumption, maybe you can make a different assumption, like "take everything up until the next empty line as the object":

```
pattern = r"^var productArticleDetails = (.+?^\s*$)"
```

If this is still too brittle and the object could be in any form, then we run into balanced parenthesis detection problems that regex isn't well-suited for. You can use a stack to figure out when the object ends (be careful if the data contains `}` inside strings, but that's a navigable parsing problem).

Note that `ast.literal_eval()` fails if the JS object doesn't have quotes around its keys, so you may need to resort to some preparation for that case as well. It's unclear whether this is a static, one-shot parse you need, or if you're looking for a robust solution that can withstand any JS object format.

`json.loads` is pretty useless here because it assumes perfectly well-formed JSON. JS objects are almost never in such a form, as shown here.

Comment: could you complete that match till the last occurrence of `}` [here](https://regex101.com/r/nGGOx5/2) once you done , press CTRL + S

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking for?

Comment: how to match till the last occurrence of `}` I've been able to match till the first `{` , i want to complete this regex till the end

Comment: I don't think that'd be very useful because the script almost certainly will contain multiple objects or brace blocks but you can do `productArticleDetails\s=\s{(\n|.)*}` or use dotall.

Comment: @ggloren thank you. got it. just for notice. `pyjsparser` can parse bad formatted `JSON` something like the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60523964/7658985)

Comment: Yeah, there are always third party libraries, but I tend to treat that as the last resort. We aren't given much information about the file we're parsing or the use case. It seems premature to try to speculate on what they need. It could be pretty much anything.

Comment: there's error on `if m:
        = re.search(pattern, script.text, re.M | re.S):`

Comment: That's Python 3.8 syntax.

Comment: I’m using python 3.8 actually and that’s not works on my end ! Are you sure ?

Comment: Works fine for me. `Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50)` is what I'm on.